# How to change mlmultiarray to string

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, coreml, coremltools

I am using a CoreML converted from a TensorFlow model for iOS. When I converted, the output is mlmultiarray, instead of the expected dictionary and string types.
Thus, the output would not be readable at all.
How would you fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add your approach(code) here.

Comment: Doc states : "Multidimensional arrays are commonly used to represent input and output data. Often, each dimension of a multidimensional array has an associated label or meaning". So please tell what are the different dimensions of the multiArray you get.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the model from TF to Core ML, you need to tell the converter this is a classifier. The easiest way to do this is to provide a text file (or array) containing the class labels when you run the converter.